# Append string at the end of each line in comma separated words in Shell scripts

Tags: shell, unix

I have a csv file with comma separated fields like shown below.. I need to read only first line.

```
Test1,Test2,Test3,Test4
```

So I am able to split these comma separated values and print it on separate lines like..

```
Test1 
Test2
Test3
Test4
```

Using below code

```
-cat $f | head -1 | sed 's/,/\n/g'
```

Where $f is variable to pass the csv file name.

Now I want to append "string," at the end of each line so that my output looks like..

```
Test1 string,
Test2 string,
Test3 string,
Test4 string
```

How can I do that using above code?

Comment: Append `|sed 's/$/string/g'` in the given code.

Comment: `at the end of each line` - except for the last line, where you want to append just `string` without the comma, so not each line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using sed:

```
sed '1{s/,\|$/ string&/g;s/,/&\n/g;q}' file
```

Comment: Hi Oguz ismail , Thanks for your reply. it is coming correctly till the last column but when it is printing the last column then it is printing as below Quarter string ,
 string Date

Comment: E.g Code for reading csv files in folder..
for f in `hadoop fs -ls $FILES | awk '{print $NF}' | grep .csv$ | tr '\n' ' '`
do


hadoop fs -cat $f | head -1 |  sed '1{s/,\|$/ string&/g;s/,/&\n/g;q}'

done 
and suppose file contains only two columns called Quarter and Date as shown below 
Quarter,Date 
so I want to print the output as follows 
Quarter String,
Date String

Comment: I didn't really understand, but make sure your file doesn't have DOS line endings, then if it still don't work let me know

Comment: output from shell script 
-sh-4.1$ sh ReadAllFiles.sh
Quarter string,
 string
-sh-4.1$

Comment: Okay, okay. That happens when your input has DOS line endings (i.e has an extra `\r` at the end of line), and you need to get rid of it. You can use `tr -d '\r'` for that, or prepend `s/\r//;` to the sed script. And btw you don't need `head -1` there, the command I gave handles that

Answer (score 0):

**Use `awk`**

eg:

```
cat your_csv_file | awk -F, '{print $1}'
```

Illustration

```
root@virtual-machine:~# echo "Test1,Test2,Test3,Test4"| awk -F, '{print $1}'
Test1
```